# Inconsistent cypher query results in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For illustrating this issue, create thousand nodes labeled z having incrementing numeric attribute zid.

```
FOREACH (i IN range(1, 1000)| CREATE (z:z { zid: i }));
```

Now find a node using random zid value between 1 and 1000.

```
MATCH (n:z { zid: round(rand()*1000)}) 
RETURN n;
```

The above cypher returns inconsistent results, sometimes no nodes are returned, sometimes multiple nodes are returned.

Tweaking the cypher as follows yields consistent results.

```
WITH round(rand()*1000) AS x
MATCH (n:z { zid: x })
RETURN x, n;
```

What is wrong with the first cypher query ?

Comment: Which values do the multiple nodes have that are returned? No nodes are returned if rand()*1000 evaluates to zero as you didn't create any nodes with id zero.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are receiving inconsistent results with the first query has to do with how Neo4j evaluates Cypher queries. The function `round(rand()*1000)` is evaluated for each of the items within the label index for `z` when using `WHERE` or concise syntax. When you use the `WITH` clause, the function is evaluated once.

That being said, this looks like a bug that is specific to the `rand()` function.